# Touchpad issues after upgrading to new version 5.1

Tags: touchpad, release-hera

I upgraded today to version 5.1 Hera, but after updating the notebook touchpad stopped working. notebook: Lenovo Ideapad S145.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Olá,

Apparently he would have to update the kernel, I answered someone a few minutes ago on another post.

https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/a/21346/19360

Launch the terminal whithout mouse and shortcut for terminal

1. SUPER + Space
2. Search terminal or the name of your terminal
3. Follow instruction in the link to the top

Comment: Ok, it worked. thank you