# Will elementary OS 5 Juno upgrade to 5.1 Hera automatically?

Tags: updates, release-hera

elementary OS 5.1 just launched and I have 5.0 installed. I wish to know if it will be upgraded automatically running some command or with some native software of the OS.

Comment: just install updates in appcenter and you are done ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to update elementary OS 5.0 to 5.1 you can use the classic manual method

```
$ sudo apt update
$ sudo apt upgrade
$ sudo apt dist-upgrade
$ sudo reboot
```

check if you are in elementary OS 5.1 after reboot

```
$ cat /etc/os-release 
NAME="elementary OS"
VERSION="5.1 Hera"
ID=elementary
ID_LIKE=ubuntu
PRETTY_NAME="elementary OS 5.1 Hera"
LOGO=distributor-logo
VERSION_ID="5.1"
HOME_URL="https://elementary.io/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://elementary.io/support"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://github.com/elementary/os/issues/new"
PRIVACY_POLICY_URL="https://elementary.io/privacy-policy"
VERSION_CODENAME=hera
UBUNTU_CODENAME=bionic
```

---

EDIT

If your want to update your kernel you can do that

Check your kernel version

```
$ uname -r                                                                            
4.15.0-72-generic
```

Update your kernel

```
$ sudo apt install --install-recommends linux-generic-hwe-18.04 xserver-xorg-hwe-18.04

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  linux-headers-5.0.0-37 linux-headers-5.0.0-37-generic linux-headers-generic-hwe-18.04 linux-image-5.0.0-37-generic linux-image-generic-hwe-18.04
  linux-modules-5.0.0-37-generic linux-modules-extra-5.0.0-37-generic xserver-xorg-core-hwe-18.04 xserver-xorg-input-all-hwe-18.04 xserver-xorg-input-libinput-hwe-18.04
  xserver-xorg-legacy-hwe-18.04 xserver-xorg-video-all-hwe-18.04 xserver-xorg-video-amdgpu-hwe-18.04 xserver-xorg-video-ati-hwe-18.04 xserver-xorg-video-fbdev-hwe-18.04
  xserver-xorg-video-intel-hwe-18.04 xserver-xorg-video-nouveau-hwe-18.04 xserver-xorg-video-qxl-hwe-18.04 xserver-xorg-video-radeon-hwe-18.04
  xserver-xorg-video-vesa-hwe-18.04 xserver-xorg-video-vmware-hwe-18.04
Suggested packages:
  fdutils linux-hwe-doc-5.0.0 | linux-hwe-source-5.0.0 linux-hwe-tools xfonts-100dpi | xfonts-75dpi firmware-amd-graphics xserver-xorg-video-r128 xserver-xorg-video-mach64
  firmware-misc-nonfree
Recommended packages:
  xserver-xorg-input-wacom-hwe-18.04
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  xserver-xorg xserver-xorg-core xserver-xorg-input-all xserver-xorg-input-evdev xserver-xorg-input-libinput xserver-xorg-input-wacom xserver-xorg-legacy
  xserver-xorg-video-all xserver-xorg-video-amdgpu xserver-xorg-video-ati xserver-xorg-video-fbdev xserver-xorg-video-intel xserver-xorg-video-nouveau
  xserver-xorg-video-qxl xserver-xorg-video-radeon xserver-xorg-video-vesa xserver-xorg-video-vmware
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  linux-generic-hwe-18.04 linux-headers-5.0.0-37 linux-headers-5.0.0-37-generic linux-headers-generic-hwe-18.04 linux-image-5.0.0-37-generic linux-image-generic-hwe-18.04
  linux-modules-5.0.0-37-generic linux-modules-extra-5.0.0-37-generic xserver-xorg-core-hwe-18.04 xserver-xorg-hwe-18.04 xserver-xorg-input-all-hwe-18.04
  xserver-xorg-input-libinput-hwe-18.04 xserver-xorg-legacy-hwe-18.04 xserver-xorg-video-all-hwe-18.04 xserver-xorg-video-amdgpu-hwe-18.04 xserver-xorg-video-ati-hwe-18.04
  xserver-xorg-video-fbdev-hwe-18.04 xserver-xorg-video-intel-hwe-18.04 xserver-xorg-video-nouveau-hwe-18.04 xserver-xorg-video-qxl-hwe-18.04
  xserver-xorg-video-radeon-hwe-18.04 xserver-xorg-video-vesa-hwe-18.04 xserver-xorg-video-vmware-hwe-18.04
0 upgraded, 23 newly installed, 17 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 69,9 MB of archives.
After this operation, 331 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n]
...
...
...
```

reboot your elementary OS

```
$ reboot
```

check your kernel version

```
$ uname -r
5.0.0-37-generic
```

Comment: You should also add `sudo apt install --install-recommends linux-generic-hwe-18.04 xserver-xorg-hwe-18.04` to update the kernel.

Comment: Thank you I add this line

Comment: Thank you! This worked perfectly.

Comment: We really should not be directing users to Terminal for something as simple as running updates. Updating in AppCenter is all that is needed.

Comment: That why I say "if you want"

Comment: I prefer to use terminal :)

Answer (score 2):

It should upgrade automatically

Comment: Not automatically; the user has to install updates from AppCenter.