# Can't Install Elementary 5.1

Tags: system-installation, release-hera

I have an HP laptop with Windows and Elementary OS Loki but when trying to install Hera it just keeps hanging in "Detecting filesystem".
I had a similar issue installing Juno but only kept crashing while in the installation menu (gave up after several tries).

Basically I have a few partitions:

- /home
- / (Loki)
- /swap
- between 5 and 8 Windows' partitions (they were created automatically, I guess)

While installing, I keep the /home and /swap and choose Hera to install in the Loki partition. I proceed and after checking if the changes are ok it says this:

> the installer needs to commit changes to partition tables, but cannot
>   do so because partitions on the following mount points could not be
>   unmounted:
>
> /cdrom
>
> Please close any applications using these mount points
>
> Would you like the installer to try to unmount these partitions again?

I click continue and the "Detecting filesystem" window appears and in the details it says:

```
elementary ubiquity[3990]: Step_before = stepUserInfo
elementary systemd[1]: Starting Cleanup of Temporary Directories...
elementary systemd[1]: Started Cleanup of Temporary Directories.
```

After a few minutes it says:

```
elementary CRON [16065]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
```

And it repeats the same thing every hour...

Tried with [this](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1645214&page=2&p=10241015#post10241015) but didn't work. Could anyone help?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is there a reason for not having passed your elementary OS Loki to Hera via a classic update `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade && sudo apt dist-upgrade` ?

Comment: It doesn't update to Hera via classic update (just tried again), I think it only works from Juno.

Answer (score 0):

I might be wrong, but I am almost sure that before I installed Juno I read somewhere that it was recommended to remove older versions of elementary before installing. I had no previous versions, so I didn't put all too much attention to it and went on with the parts pertinent to my installation.
So the question would be: did you remove Loki beofre attempting to install Juno? Once you got Juno, Hera will come automatically, but apparently it's not the case with Loki-to-Juno upgrade.

Comment: Shouldn't that be the same as formatting the Loki partition to install Juno/Hera? How do I remove Loki from said partition before installing Hera?

Comment: Well, as I said I didn't have to do it, but I figure yes, formatting the partition should erase everything in it. If you formatted and still got error, then I would ask: did you try to install Hera directly? I think you should rather install Juno first, and then upgrade it using the AppCenter. After that you might want to read the thread about updating the kernel, which you do using the terminal.

Comment: I tried installing Juno before and just crashed during the installation menu. Tried it several times with the same result of everything freezing and not working.

Comment: the thread about updating the kernel is here: https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/21339/will-elementary-os-5-juno-upgrade-to-5-1-hera-automatically/21346#21346

Comment: Did you check the sum, if it matches? Maybe you got a bad copy. Try downloading from another mirror. Did you use Rufus? Did you format both /home and / or just /? Don't forget to backup your data first!

Comment: Ah, yes. I checked that back then when trying to update to Juno. Also tried downloading 2 or 3 times into different USB drives.

Comment: Well, when I got Juno, there was a number, a checksum, which you should make sure matches the one from the copy you got to ensure no parting is missing or defekt or altered. Use Rufus, the number of the copy will appear in rufus window so you check before pressing the go button (or install or whatever the button was labeled). https://linuxhint.com/install_elementary_os_5_juno/

Comment: I did that: used Rufus from Windows and UNetbootin from Loki but the result was the same. Also tried with diffent USB drives.

Comment: https://linuxhint.com/install_elementary_os_5_juno/ I followed each step in this link and had no problems installing. Give it another try despite the fact you tried  it before, don't skip steps (before it didn't work, so now do it as they say) and choose another mirror to download from. And clean the USB before reusing. It's worth a try, if it doesn't work again you stay in same situation you're already in, but it might work.

Comment: I'm running out of suggestions. :D

Comment: Last try: The error says something about ubiquitous, so I think it has to be related to the partitions (one or more than one is not being cleaned so when it tries to install there are elements of other system there). I would suggest you to remove the partitions (try Gparted or something alike), remove all the partitions Loki was using, /home, / and /swap and if you had others, they too. then start from scratch. It should do the trick.

Comment: @covxy So, did you try it? Did it work this time around?

Comment: Tried installing Juno again and it crashed. The other thing with the partitions I didn't try it because I'm avoiding to remove them in the first place. Thanks for the help, though.