# Touchpad stopped working after Hera 5.1 update

Tags: touchpad, release-hera

My trackpad stopped working after updating form Juno to Hera, now I'm forced to use a mouse.

[image: system info]

from my xinput list the touchpas seems to be recognized:

```
Virtual core pointer                        id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
Virtual core XTEST pointer                  id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
USB OPTICAL MOUSE                       id=10   [slave  pointer  (2)]
Synaptics TM3108-002                        id=12   [slave  pointer  (2)]
Virtual core keyboard                       id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
Virtual core XTEST keyboard                 id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
Power Button                                id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
Video Bus                                   id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
Power Button                                id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
Sleep Button                                id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
Integrated_Webcam_HD: Integrate             id=11   [slave  keyboard (3)]
Dell WMI hotkeys                            id=13   [slave  keyboard (3)]
AT Translated Set 2 keyboard                id=14   [slave  keyboard (3)]
DELL Wireless hotkeys                       id=15   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

I tried installing synaptic drivers which seemed to be missing:

```
sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-input-synaptics
```

but that didn't solve anything.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see you do not have the new Kernel tried to update it

```
$ sudo apt install --install-recommends linux-generic-hwe-18.04 xserver-xorg-hwe-18.04
```

I think that will solve your problem, someone else also had this problem [here](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/q/21337/19360)

[image: elementaryos_about]

Comment: I just followed the link instructions and the kernel update worked like a charm, thank you!

Comment: You're welcome, it seems that with Hera it is necessary to update the kernel for the TouchPad to be functional.

Answer (score 1):

had exactly the same problem. The above-mentioned didn't help.
For me I had to install the synaptic driver from the terminal. Even I didn't need the driver before, I need it now..

```
apt-get install xserver-xorg-input-synaptics xserver-xorg-input-synaptics-dev-hwe-16.04 xserver-xorg-core
```

Before xinput didn't show the device. After installig the driver xinput shows it
SYNA3602:00 0911:5288 Touchpad