# Touchpad not working upon re-login - X1 Carbon

Tags: updates, touchpad, lenovo

Following one of the latest updates (I had a few pending, so not sure which one), my touchpad is acting a bit weird.

On boot and first login, everything works fine. When the screen locks and I log in again, some touchpad features do not work anymore:

- Two finger scrolling
- Right click with 2 fingers

I updated to a newer kernel following another [post](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/21492/trackpad-breaks-on-upgrade-to-5-1) in the forum, since I had noticed that my kernel was way behind. This is the current situation:

[image]

Not sure want to do. Any tips?

Thanks!

Comment: I did a fresh Elementary OS install and updated to the latest firmware but I still have the same problem.

Comment: I installed Ubuntu 19.10 and things seem to work fine. I did try Ubuntu 18.04 but the problem persisted. So I suppose this is a software package issue.

On Ubuntu 19.10 the kernel is 5.3.0-40-generic. I hope someone can help. In the meantime I am off Elementary .